# What is a word that express the quality of a person thinking his thing is missing but it is just right next to him?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

My child is looking for a pencil case in her heap of toys.

She screams "where is my pencil case?" and then throws a tantrum.

I come to the heap and immediately see the pencil case almost right on the top of the heap.

Is it correct to say "**You are such a forgetful person!**"?

Or **do we have a word (it could be a noun or an adjective) that express the quality of a person who is thinking his thing is missing but actually that thing is just right next to him or in front of him?**

Comment: _Forgetful_ isn't appropriate here. You might say "It's right under your nose!" or "You can't see it for looking at it", which is an idiom for not noticing something which is right there in front of you.

Answer (score 1):

One possible phrase for it could be **Inattentional blindness** there is a long [article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness) explaining this. Other similar phenomena are mentioned in the "See Also" section of this article.

Another possible way of defining it is OCD. The person expects an object to be in a particular place (and no other) so if it is moved, even a short distance, they can no longer find it.

I can't find a single word or phrase you could use in a conversation. There is **apraxia** but this is a neurological condition, not a temporary , tantrum inducing, state of most children.